# How do I use expressions outside of ng-repeat scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I'm making a job board built in AngularJS and Craft CMS. Users can register, login and create a job posting. The job postings are being fetched from a json file and displayed on the index page using ng-repeat. I want the user to be able to click each job posting and have that specific job posting open up inside a modal on the same page (to keep them on the same page) which is where my problem is.

Since the modal is generated outside of the ng-repeat, the expressions don't work. Here's my example.

```
<div class="jobs">

        <div class="job-panel" ng-repeat="job in jobs>
            <a href=""><h3>{{ '{{job.title}}' }}</h3></a>
            <p><strong>Location: </strong>{{ '{{job.jobCity}}' }}, {{ '{{job.jobState}}' }} <strong>Post Date: </strong>{{ '{{job.postDate}}' }}</p>
            <p><strong>Job Category: </strong>{{ '{{job.jobCategory}}' }}</p>
            <p><strong>Job Overview: </strong>{{ '{{job.jobOverview}}' }} <a class="show-details" data-remodal-target="modal">(details)</a></p>

            <div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal"
                data-remodal-options="hashTracking: false">
            <h3>{{job.title}}</h3>
            <p><strong>Location: </strong>{{ '{{job.jobCity}}' }}, {{ '{{job.jobState}}' }} <strong>Post Date: </strong>{{ '{{job.postDate}}' }}</p>
            <p><strong>Job Category: </strong>{{ '{{job.jobCategory}}' }}</p>
            <p><strong>Job Overview: </strong>{{ '{{job.jobOverview}}' }}</p> 
            </div>

        </div>

</div>
```

Everything inside the "job-panel" divs is displayed fine, however the modal div inside it doesn't grab the same expressions so when a user opens up the modal they can only see the text without the expressions. I'm going to assume because the jQuery plugin it uses (Remodal) generates the html on the top level HTML alongside my container and not inside the job-panel div where I've placed it. I need a way to have the user click the (details) link and view more information from the JSON file inside the modal.

Here's images of what the site looks like. The first is the index view with the postings listed and the second is how the modal is currently generated.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYGL7.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkY5H.png)